# excel vba finding named range in specific order

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I create named range dynamically using vba. Then I want to export to word in each named range in each page. E.g: Named range would be Page1,Page2,...Page10...etc. When I try to export, Page1 comes first and page10 comes second. How to make it page1,page2, etc...

```
For intCounter = 1 To wbBook.Names.Count
      MsgBox Names(intCounter).name
       'If IsNameRefertoSheet(oSht, Names(intCounter)) Then
        If Names(intCounter).name Like "Page*" Then
            With objDoc
                 Set rtarget = .Range(.Content.End - 1, .Content.End - 1)
                 'Insert page break if not first page
                 If Names(intCounter).name <> "Page1" Then rtarget.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
                 'Copy data from named range
                 Range(wbBook.Names(intCounter)).Copy
                 Set rtarget = .Range(.Content.End - 1, .Content.End - 1)
                 rtarget.Paste
            End With
        End If
       'End If
    Next intCounter
```

Comment: "Page10" indeeds comes before "Page2" in any alphabetical sort. Pad your numbers with zeroes to make that "Page001" instead; that way "Page010" will always come after "Page002".

Comment: @Mat'sMug, its worked as you suggested. Thank you verymuch!

Answer (score 0):

a proposition

```
nbrofpage=10 'set your number of pages
For intcounter = 1 To nbrofpage
    With objDoc
        Set rtarget = .Range(.Content.End - 1, .Content.End - 1)
        'Insert page break if not first page
        If intcounter <> 1 Then rtarget.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
        'Copy data from named range
        Range("page" & intcounter).Copy
        Set rtarget = .Range(.Content.End - 1, .Content.End - 1)
        rtarget.Paste
    End With
Next intcounter
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Work book has many named range. When I export to word for specific named range from particular sheet, it is showing different order and also through clipboard error. Any alternative or help would be much appreciated. thank you!

Comment: Changing the name from page1 to page001 , page002 etc worked. thank you!